# SQLite : Hyphens getting replaced with â€“

Tags: sqlite

I am inserting values like `CC1 - MasterCard 3456` into my SQLite database (using phonegap).
But somehow the inserted values look like `CC1 â€“ MasterCard 3456`

The hyphen `-` seems to be getting replaced with `â€“`

Whats the deal?

Comment: Are you sure you insert the [Unicode Character 'HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm) and not some other character?

Comment: Yes :)
Sorry aboutthat...

Question is invalid now. I had copy pasted that value from MS Word document and that is why it was showing something else.
After manually typing that "-" its working fine now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is external to sqlite.  Some text editors/applications will replace hyphens, quotes, etc for whatever reason.  Wordpress is terribly annoying about this.